# Replacing 'unit' with 'pcs' in a sentence while keeping 'unity' unchanged in PHP

Tags: php, replace

I want to ask besides using str_replace what should I use to replace? I have code :
`echo str_replace("Unit", "pcs", "Unity Scoop Neck Cap Sleeve Tee")`
The output results are : "pcsy Scoop Neck Cap Sleeve Tee"

But I want the result to still be "Unity Scoop Neck Cap Sleeve Tee", I want if there is the word "unity" it doesn't change to "pcs" but if the word in the sentence has the word "unit" then it changes to "pcs"

Comment: Go look into regular expressions, and _word boundaries_ in that context.

Comment: There is a quick fix which might work for most/all of your cases: `str_replace("Unit ", "pcs", "Unity Scoop Neck Cap Sleeve Tee")`. That is, force the search to only care about full words, presumably always including a blank space afterwards. The only problem with this is that the last element would be missed, unless it includes a specific character afterwards which you should include too. In any case, this seems a pretty naive approach. Ideally, you should carefully think about all the possible inputs and properly account for them.